# Why is apk build on Windows different from one built on Linux/Mac OS?

Tags: android, linux, windows, macos, apk

I have two apks build from the same source code.

1. They are different in size MacOS about 19 vs  Windows about 16 MB
2. They have different count of dex files when unzipped in studio apkanalyzer Windows - classes(1-3).dex, MacOS classes(1-15).dex .
   In general the files sizes here and there are different.

[image: How is it possible if the source code is just the same. The build tool is gradle so the configuration is just there. The same as well]

Comment: how did you build those apks? Do they have same build variant (debuag/release and same flavor) ?

Comment: both are the same flavour

Comment: I build them from studio gradle side panel with assembleMyBuildType command

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how the gradle build is running.

My wild guess is that the gradle build on macOs is building the debug version where the code shrinking rules don't apply (R8)
and on Windows it's a release build with R8 on.

But to pinpoint the problem here you can check the differences between `gradle.bat` for Windows and `gradlew` executable for Mac in your app's root folder.

Comment: I specifically took apks from app/build/outputs/apk/qa folder
and checked my qa config , and I have minifyEnabled - false there.
So both shouldn't be minified